# Udev rule calls script and that script calls another script with a variable and the variable is empty

Tags: udev

When I call a script that was called by udev and then I pass a variable from that script to another script the variable is empty.

Udev calls this script:
`a.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello () {
    /foo/bar/b.sh $1
}

hello "test"
```

`/foo/bar/b.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $@
```

but the echo is empty why?

Comment: @steeldriver I added one

Comment: @steeldriver youre right. In the real script I dont echo the variable I post it to a webhook using curl.